# exclude ".txt" file from being transferred - Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have several files in a folder:

piratesCaribbean_part001
piratesCaribbean_part002
name.txt

I want to exclude the name.txt from being transferred when I transfer files to another folder. Because the other 2 files have no extensions, I cannot specify an extension to filter out what files I want to be transferred.

How do I do this in Java?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "Because the other 2 files have no extensions, I cannot specify an extension to filter out what files I want to be transferred." - Why not? Not having an extension is different to having the extension `.txt`, you'll just need to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

well it would be always good to show your codes.

anyway,
for your problem:
create a filter (implements `java.io.FileFilter` interface). and get files with that filter.

Comment: and within the FileFilter's `accept(File f)`, just return `! f.getName().endsWith(".txt")`.